# Stop MKMapView from moving to user's current location when user moves the map

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am making an app to show some places near the user's current location. When the user moves the map, the map moves the user to his current location, over and over again. So, the user can't see the annotations on the map, because if he moves the map, the map goes back to his current location.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
if (userLocation)
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000);
    MKCoordinateRegion regionDelMapa = [self.mapa regionThatFits:region];
    if(isnan(regionDelMapa.center.latitude))
    {
        NSLog(@"Bad region...");
    }else
    {
        [self.mapa setRegion:regionDelMapa animated:YES];
    }
}   
}
```

I have tried some other answers here, but nothing happens. This is not the desired behavior, so how can I stop updating the user's current location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[self.mapa setRegion:regionDelMapa animated:YES];
```

That line sets the map region. You're executing that code every time you get an update, thus reseting the area that the map covers. If you don't want the map to re-center itself on the user's location at each update, remove that code from the `-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` method.

If you want to center the map on the user *once* and then allow the user to scroll away from that location, use Core Location to get the user's location.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this API  : `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`
Add this in your function `didUpdateUserLocation` .